# Ruby evaluate an expression with regex, no eval

Tags: ruby, regex, eval

Sorry if this is duplicated.  I thought I'd reword my question a little bit.

How could I use regex to evaluate a mathematical expression?  Without using the eval function.

Example expressions:

```
math1 = "1+1"
math2 = "3+2-1"
```

I would like it to work for a variable number of numbers in the expression like I showed in the example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby evalute without eval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994101/ruby-evalute-without-eval)

Comment: So just numbers and addition/subtraction? Why don't you write a parser instead?

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier yeah i know, its a slightly different question..thanks for checking up on me though bro

Comment: What about `send`, is that allowed?

Comment: Yeah.  How could I use that?

Comment: @Tommy I'm just working that out :)

Comment: @Tommy have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I mean I can match the regex fine.  I just have no idea how you can evaluate any math expressions without using eval.

Comment: Try `3.send :-, 4`, or `12.send :+, 5` to see what I mean about using `send`.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a bad idea. Regexp is not a parser, nor an evaluator.

Use a grammar to describe your expressions.  Parse it with a formal parser like the lovely ruby gem [Treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/). Then evaluate the abstract syntax tree (AST) produced by the parser.

Gosh, Treetop's [arithmetic example](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop/tree/master/examples/lambda_calculus) practically gives you the solution for free.

Comment: +1 "This is just a bad idea". +1 "Regexp is not a parser, nor an evaluator". -1 "Use a grammar to describe your expressions" - the examples given by the OP _are_ regular, and hence a RegEx can properly describe this (simplistic) grammar, a formal parser could be seen as overkill. -1 "Treetop's arithmetic example practically gives you the solution for free." - And looking at that grammar, there's proof of overkill.  1+1-1-1=0 :-)

Comment: Ah come on, @Sepster. 99% of the time when someone wants to "parse expressions" they ultimately mean a variety of arithmetic operators with varying precedence and parenthesis to group -- which is _not_ regular. It always ends in tears until they learn to parse. This is 50+ year old technology, we need to stop pulling out the wrong tool.

Comment: Agreed.  But the question didn't say anything about "parsing expression", rather, it says in its title "evaluate an expression with _regex_" and in its body "How _could_ I use _regex_ to evaluate a mathematical expression?".  Which is not to suggest I think that it _should_ be done this way.  Just that it _can_ be done.  And btw +1 because I've never seen Treetop before.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but I wrote a gem for evaluating arbitrary mathematical expressions (and it doesn't use eval internally): https://github.com/rubysolo/dentaku

Answer (score 0):

For addition and subtraction, this should work

`(?:(/d+)([-+]))+(/d+)`

This means:

- one or more digits, followed by exactly one plus or minus
- the above can be repeated as many times as required (this is a non capturing group)
- and then must end with one or more digits.

Note that each individual number and sign are captured in groups 1..n

So to evaluate, you could take captures 1 and 3, applying the sign from capture 2. Then apply the sign from capture 4 (if it exists) with the previous result and the number from capture 5 (which must exist if capture 4 exists) and so on...

So to evaluate, in psuedo code:

```
  i=1
  result=capture(i)
  loop while i <= (n-2) (where n is the capture count):
    If capture(i+1) == "-" // is subtraction 
       result = result - capture(i+2)
    Else // is addition 
       result = result + capture(i+2)
    End if
    i = i + 2
  End while
```

This is only going to work for simple addition and subtraction like in the examples you provided, as it relies on left to right associativity. As others have suggested, you'll probably need to properly parse anything more complex, eg by building a tree of nodes that can then be evaluated in the correct (depth-first?) order.

Comment: Well that will match it.  What about evaluating it without eval?

Comment: @Tommy sorry misunderstood. Have updated the answer with an algorithm to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is really messy…

```
  math2 = "12+3-4"
  head, *tail = math2.scan(/(?<digits>\d+)(?<op>[\+\-\*\/])?/)
  .map{|(digits,op)| 
    [digits.to_i,op]
  }
  .reverse

  tail.inject(head.first){|sum,(digits,op)|
    op.nil? ? 
      digits : 
      digits.send(op,sum) 
    }
  # => 11
```

You should really consider a [parser](https://github.com/mjijackson/citrus#readme) though.