# ruby function multiple parameters

Tags: ruby, calculator

I am currently playing with creating a one function to create a simple calculator. I am learning Ruby/Python. So far I am playing with Ruby to see if I can grasp it easier than Python. I was reading a ebook and came across how to use multiple parameters in a function.

```
#!/bin/ruby

def menu()
  print <<MENU
    1.Add
    2.Subtract
    3.Multiply
    4.Divide
MENU
end

def calc(a=number, b=operator, c=number, d=operator, e=number)
  puts "Answer: #{a} #{b} #{c} #{d} #{e}"
end
puts "Enter formula, seperated by comma"
a,b,c,d,e = gets()
calc(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Is my source, keep in mind this is not meant to be a used program. As it is right now, it is prints the "answer" as a string.

So, if I enter `1+3`, answer is `1+3`. But if I use `gets().to_f`, it prints `1.0` every time. If I enter the math problem in the text file, it works perfectly, just not from user input.

Comment: There are a few issues here.  What do you mean by "enter the math problem in the text file"?  What exactly do you enter in the text file?

Comment: I'm going to assume that when you use `gets()` it is only seeing what you entered as a single argument, IE `1+3` as a string, instead of three separate values. With this in mind, when you call `to_f` on the string, it will find the first non number character and discard it and everything after it. Which would be the equivalent of doing `"1".to_f`. Which would return `1.0`.

Comment: What I mean by when I enter the math problem, e.g(2*7+1) in the source code like, a,b,c,d,e=2*7+1, it will print out the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that all that what is missing in your code is to `split` the `gets` answer:

```
#!/bin/ruby

def menu()
  print <<MENU
    1.Add
    2.Subtract
    3.Multiply
    4.Divide
MENU
end

def calc(a, b, c, d, e)
  puts "Answer: #{a} #{b} #{c} #{d} #{e}"
end
puts "Enter formula, seperated by comma"
a,b,c,d,e = gets.split('')
calc(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Now, when the user will input `2*7+1` you will get `Answer: 2 * 7 + 1`, and you can go and implement your code:

```
def calc(a, b=:+, c=0, d=:+, e=0)
  puts a.to_f.send(b, c.to_f).send(d, e.to_f)
end
```

Now your answer will be `15.0`.

***DO NOT USE EVAL***, especially when you expect something structured - it is a serious security flaw!

---

For your code to support less than 5 elements, you need to change it to:

```
params = gets.chomp.split('')
calc(*params)
```

This way, missing elements will not be evaluated as 'nil', and the method's default parameter values will kick in.

Comment: It nearly works, I replaced the code with your's and get for 8*9 calc.rb:4:in `calc': undefined method ` (NoMethodError)
' for 72.0:Float
 from calc.rb:8:in `<main>'

Comment: @ndowens added an addendum for less elements than 5

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a few things going on here.

First, your function definition:
`def calc(a=number, b=operator, c=number, d=operator, e=number)`

This should probably be `def calc(a=nil, b=nil, c=nil, d=nil, e=nil)`

I understand that the example is telling me, the user, that `a` should be a number, `b` should be an operator, etc, but when you actually define a function that way, what you are doing is setting default values for the parameters.  When you use 'number' and 'operator' in the definition, these have no value and end up assigning nil as default.  The end result is the same, but it's confusing to anyone reading the code.

Next, I understand what you are trying to do with `a,b,c,d,e = gets()`.
If you just run

```
a,b,c,d,e = 1,2,3,4,5
puts a,b,c,d,e #=>
1
2
3
4
5
```

Makes sense.  However, when you run a Ruby script and use `gets()`, then everything that is input at the command line is received as a single string.  Therefore when `a,b,c,d,e = gets()` is executed, the user input of "1+3" is taken as a string and assigned to `a`.
`b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` are `nil`

You then call `calc("1+3",nil,nil,nil,nil)`.
`calc` then evaluates its one line method definition like so:
`puts "Answer: #{"1+3"} #{nil} #{nil} #{nil} #{nil}"`
And that's why you just see "Answer: 1+3" as the output.

So, why does it work if you hard code `a,b,c,d,e=2*7+1`?
When that line is evaluated, `2*7+1` is evaluated first (15).  15 is then assigned to `a` and all the other variables are `nil`, like before.  Then `calc` just prints out the value of `a`, which is 15.

So....Let's look at how to make the example work as you expect.
First, I'm going to ignore the `menu` method since it's not actually used anywhere in the example.

```
#!/bin/ruby

def calc(user_input)
  result = eval(input_string)
  puts "Answer: #{result}"
end
puts "Enter formula"

user_input = gets()
# e.g. "1+3*8"

calc(user_input)
```

All I'm doing is `eval`uating the entered string.  **Be very careful with `eval`**.  I would never actually use it in this case since a user could enter any kind of ruby script and your program would just run it.  [Here is an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994101/ruby-evalute-without-eval) that demonstrates how to implement checks before evaluating the formula.

Comment: Awesome, sorry for the newbie question. The menu part of the code was the starting and forgot to get rid of it. I was reading an ebook on ruby and remember seeing how to pass multiple parameters and wanted to try it and see if it would work fine. I still have plenty to learn. I am trying to find out if I want to focus on Ruby or Python. I heard these two are the easiest to learn.

Comment: Cool.  Please click the checkmark to accept my answer if you are satisfied.  Good luck.  Ruby is fun!